# Two Namespace need each other

Tags: c++

How to write namespace that need each other?
something like this:

```
namespace AMXe
{
    void Register(AMX *amx);
    void Release(AMX *amx);
    struct s_AMXe
    {
        Command::s_command command;
    };
    extern std::unordered_map<AMX*, s_AMXe*> *list;
}

namespace Command
{
    extern DWORD OnPlayerCommandText_Addr;

    void Initialize();
    void RegisterAllFromAmx(AMX* amx, AMXe::s_AMXe* amxData);
    cell Command_AddAltNamed_N(AMX *amx, cell *params);
    struct s_command
    {
        int OnPlayerCommandReceived;
        int OnPlayerCommandPerformed;
    };
}
```

When i compile this code, i got warning that Command is not a namespace in "Command::s_command command;" line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `Command::s_command` is not available when you use:

```
struct s_AMXe
{
    Command::s_command command;
};
```

It makes sense that the compiler throws an error at that line.

You can forward declare names (classes, functions, etc.) inside `namespace`s just like you can forward declare global names.

After that you can use pointers and references to those types. However, to use an object of `class` in a `namespace`, the `class` must be defined first.

Also, remember that, unlike `class`es, `namespace`s can be divided into multiple blocks.

You can reorganize your code as shown below:

```
// Define Command::s_command first.
namespace Command
{
   struct s_command
   {
      int OnPlayerCommandReceived;
      int OnPlayerCommandPerformed;
   };
}

namespace AMXe
{
   void Register(AMX *amx);
   void Release(AMX *amx);
   struct s_AMXe
   {
      Command::s_command command;
   };
   extern std::unordered_map<AMX*, s_AMXe*> *list;
}

// Define rest of Command namespace
namespace Command
{
   extern DWORD OnPlayerCommandText_Addr;

   void Initialize();
   void RegisterAllFromAmx(AMX* amx, AMXe::s_AMXe* amxData);
   cell Command_AddAltNamed_N(AMX *amx, cell *params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `Command::s_command` before it is used in `AMXe::s_AMXe`.  Moreover, since it is included directly (as opposed to by pointer or reference) it needs to be defined before use (so the compiler knows what size it is).

In this particular case, the solution is simple.  Move the definition of `s_command` in front:

```
namespace Command {
    struct s_command {
        int OnPlayerCommandReceived;
        int OnPlayerCommandPerformed;
    };
}

namespace AMXe {
    etc...
}

namespace Command {
    etc...
}
```